# SalesForce LiveAgent from 21st century

Tags: liveagent, custom

is there some posibility to make LiveAgent chat window look like from 21st century? 
Something like in-site embeded chat "window" not pop-up. We had livechatinc and their "window" was awesome.

Comment: I don't think there are ready-made alternatives but you can create your own visualforce chat window (not sure if you can force it to embed in the page, though):  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_customizing_chat_windows.htm